# Повелительное наклонение глагола "ехать"

Tags: орфография, глаголы, наклонение

Глагол "ехать" не имеет повелительного наклонения. А как с глаголом "отъехать"? На многих сайтах предлагается форма "отъедь".
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Большой толковый словарь [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=отъехать&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8A%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)

**ОТЪЕХАТЬ,** -еду, -едешь; **<отъезжай>**; св. 1. Поехав, удалиться в сторону, на некоторое расстояние. О. в сторону. О. от станции. // Проехать какое-л. расстояние (от какого-л. места). О. десять вёрст. О. несколько шагов. 2. Разг.-сниж. Отстать от кого-л., прекратив просьбы, приставания. О. подобру-поздорову. О. ни с чем. 3. Разг.-сниж. Отойти, перестать плотно прилегать к чему-л. Шкаф отъехал от стены. <Отъезжать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Отъезд, -а; м. День отъезда. Быть, находиться в отъезде (временно отсутствовать, уехав куда-л.).

[Нацкорпус](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%9E%D0%A2%D0%AA%D0%95%D0%97%D0%96%D0%90%D0%99)

― Сядь в машину, **отъезжай** на бульвар и жди, ― сказал я Усману. [Валериан Скворцов. Каникулы вне закона (2001)]

Comment: Интересно, почему от глагола СВ дают повелит. форму НВ? "Отъезжай", скорее, от "отъезжать". По крайней мере, в Викисловаре так.

Comment: Повелительное наклонение глагола ехать — звиздуй! Супплетивная форма))

Comment: Это темная история... Ну, неблагозвучно, наверное.  Ведь многие фомы образуются индивидуально, по нестандартным правилам. Здесь фонетические законы вмешиваются.

Answer (score 1):

Глагол "отъехать" имеет повелительное наклонение. Что делай? - отъезжай. Что делайте? - отъезжайте.

А вот глагол "ехать" будет выглядеть в повелительном наклонении так: Что делай? - поезжай. Что делайте? - поезжайте.

Comment: Орфографический словарь
ехать, еду, едет; ПОВ. поезжай(те)  http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=ЕХАТЬ&all=x